# Lighttpd url.rewrite-if-not-file in subdir

Tags: php, zend-framework, mod-rewrite, lighttpd

I need some help with an url.rewrite-if-not-file.

I am using a Zend Framework based application so most of my requests are to be treated by 
/index.php and so far everything is good.

However, I have some sub-applications that'll have to work without that redirect.

For example, I need all requests in the dir /events to lead to that directoriy-index file.

```
"/events/" => "/events/index.php",
"/events/?foo=bar" => "/events/index.php?foo=bar",
"/events/create/" => "/events/create/index.php"
```

And so on

What I have so far is

```
url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
   "^/events/(.*)/$" => "/events/$1/index.php"
)
```

But when it comes to capturing the GET variables and place them right, I am lost.

I have tried

```
"^/events/(.*)\??(.*)$" => "/events/$1/index.php?$2"
```

But that doesn't work.

Thankful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [the last section](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs%3aModRewrite) of the docs.

So try this:

```
"^/events/([^\?]*)(\?(.*))?$" => "/events/$1/index.php?$3"
```

The difference is that the `.` in your first subpattern was greedy so it would have gobbled up the `?` character, preventing it from ever matching the other part...

Comment: Thanks alot! that (and some rewrite-order issues :) ) did the trick!